How to provide multiple responses to same prompt using Ansible expect module
I am using the Delinea adedit command (https://docs.delinea.com/online-help/server-suite/dev/adedit/commands.htm).  After issuing the adedit command in a Linux CLI a > prompt is seen and I enter the following commands in succession:
>bind acme.com administrator password123
>package require ade_lib
>add_user_to_group ...
>quit

FYI, password123 is a false password.
I am attempting to code this in Ansible using the expect command like so:
- name: Delinea adedit generic prompt with multiple different responses
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: adedit
    responses:
      ">":
        - bind "{{domain_name}} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/username', region='us-east-1') }} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/password', region='us-east-1') }}"
        - package require ade_lib
        - add_user_to_group "{{instance_name}}$@{{domain_name}} \"CN=SG-CFY-Delinea MFA Servers,OU=Computer Roles,OU=Centrify,DC=acme,DC=local\""
        - quit

and I get this response in Ansible:
changed: [SERVER01] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "adedit", "delta": "0:00:00.193347", "end": "2024-09-11 14:49:15.510734", "rc": 0, "start": "2024-09-11 14:49:15.317387", "stdout": "No entry for terminal type \"unknown\";\r\nusing dumb terminal settings.\r\n>bind \"acme.local administrator password123\"", "stdout_lines": ["No entry for terminal type \"unknown\";", "using dumb terminal settings.", ">bind \"acme.local administrator password123\""]}

It seems that all four commands are not issued in succession.  What is incorrect in my Ansible code?

It looks like instead of using an expect-like solution, you could do something like this and your commands to adedit on standard input:
  - name: Delinea adedit generic prompt with multiple different responses
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: adedit
    stdin: |
      bind "{{domain_name}} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/username', region='us-east-1') }} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/password', region='us-east-1') }}"
      package require ade_lib
      add_user_to_group "{{instance_name}}$@{{domain_name}} \"CN=SG-CFY-Delinea MFA Servers,OU=Computer Roles,OU=Centrify,DC=acme,DC=local\""
      quit

I don't have any way to test this out, but reading through the docs this looks like a possibility.

I gave that a try and I get this result:
"stderr": "No entry for terminal type "unknown";\nusing dumb terminal settings.\nNo credentials found, need user and password\nwrong # args: should be "add_user_to_group user group"", "stderr_lines": ["No entry for terminal type "unknown";", "using dumb terminal settings.", "No credentials found, need user and password", "wrong # args: should be "add_user_to_group user group""]
It says I have the wrong # args for add_user_to_group, but I do not.

It looks like you may have misquoted the arguments to add_user_to_group (there is an outside set of quotes, and then an inside set of escaped quotes). What if you rewrite that as add_user_to_group "{{instance_name}}$@{{domain_name}}" "CN=SG-CFY-Delinea MFA Servers,OU=Computer Roles,OU=Centrify,DC=acme,DC=local"?

Thanks, I tried correcting the quotes and although the Ansible task ran successfully the adedit did not successfully perform the add_user_to_group command.

I was able to get this working by creating a bash script with the adedit commands and running that.  I think that worked because I need the correct environment to run adedit.  So what I did was create this Jinja2 template called adedit.j2
#!/usr/bin/env adedit
package require ade_lib
bind {{domain_name}} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/admgtosi/username', region='us-east-1') }} {{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/ansible/windows/admgtosi/password', region='us-east-1') }}
add_user_to_group  {{instance_name}}$@{{domain_name}} "CN=SG-CFY-Delinea MFA Servers,OU=Computer Roles,OU=Centrify,DC=compucom,DC=local"
quit

Then I ran it with these Ansible tasks:
  - name: Delinea - Template of adedit.sh bash script
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: files/adedit.j2
      dest: /tmp/adedit.sh
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0754

  - name: Run the Delinea adedit.sh bash script
    command: /tmp/adedit.sh

This worked.
